# My 6edge is 32gb . I have used aproximately 13gb but in storage option it shows that 31 gb is used ... where is my rest of memory. Please clear

Tags: internal-storage, storage

This shows you all pls help my about my storage .how can i get it[image]

Comment: I have added the `storage` tag to your post, which, when clicked will bring up a full range of questions associated with your storage query. It would be very informative to read some to understand how Android uses storage, its limits, and potential remedies. Additionally, this [query](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstorage%5D+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) will limit to some useful answers.

Comment: 32 GB is the size of your /data partition. Out of which 13GB (as you mentioned) is used by /data/media. Rest of the memory is used by /data/app, /data/data and some other folders under /data. You can't view those without root.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) or search for disk usage visualiser apps to see what's taking up your space if it's not being shown by the storage app.